# Printing html to pdf not working as expected in neither pdfkit nor weasyprint

Tags: python, pdf, weasyprint, python-pdfkit

In the last week, I have been working in automating invoicing generation for an organization I support. The process is composed of 3 steps:

1. generate invoice
2. print invoice into pdf
3. send invoice attached in an e-mail

I'm having trouble in the second step where I need to print a pdf from a url returned by the invoice generation module. I have tried 2 different python modules but neither is printing the document correctly:

**I) when printing by the browser:** This is the desired result where the html is printed using full page

[image]

**II) using pdfkit:** For some reason pdfkit is considering the html has one extra page (2 instead of 1) and printing both in the same page. I have no clue it behaves like this.enter image description here

[image]

**III) printing with WeasyPrint:** Has not work either but with the opposite effect of pdfkit. The invoice wouldn't fit in the page.

To further clarify the problem, the invoice is a big html table with lots of colspan and inline styles. I would like some help to understand why the pdf are not behaving well and what should I do to fix it.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
  <title></title>    
  <style type="text/css">    a {text-decoration: none}  </style>
</head>
<body text="#000000" link="#000000" alink="#000000" vlink="#000000">
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center">
          <a name="JR_PAGE_ANCHOR_0_1"></a>
          <table style="width: 892.5px; border-collapse: collapse; empty-cells: show" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="white">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="width: 31.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 1.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 3px; height: 1.5px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 114px; height: 1.5px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 16.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 10.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 4.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 16.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 1.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 67.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 27px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 7.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 21px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 69px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 15px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 25.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 27px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 6px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 4.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 10.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 21px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 40.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 34.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 37.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 1.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 1.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 1.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 51px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 49.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 15px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 126px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 1.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td style="width: 31.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="top">  
                <td colspan="33" style="width: 892.5px; height: 30px;"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="top"> 
                <td colspan="33" style="width: 892.5px; height: 4.5px;"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="top">  
                <td style="width: 31.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>  
                <td colspan="31" style="border-top: 1.5px dashed #000000; "></td>  
                <td style="width: 31.5px; height: 1.5px;"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="top">  
                <td colspan="33" style="width: 892.5px; height: 30px;"></td>
              </tr>
              .
              .
              .
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since u r using python u can plugins like fpdf .
I myself tried html and xhtml to pdf but failed .
Fpdf plugin worked .

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Adithya! I tried `fpdf`but it started throwing different errors that I didn't go ahead in debugging. My final solution was not ideal but good to start. Instead of doing the conversion `html > pdf` I had to do a `html > png > pdf` to get the right sizing. Since most documents will be printed this method is accepted to start running the process.

Comment: @fernandosjp I know i am replying this late but it might help some others. We can use wkhtmltopdf and pdfkit for pdf generation from html -> pdf.